# How to resolve Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.Core.dll Error in ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, botframework

I have run simple application of botframework. But facing one issue like this.

```
admin@admin-desktop:~/Documents/botjs/BotFrameworkEmulator-Console$ mono BFEmulator.exe
Microsoft Bot Framework Channel Emulator v3.0.6043.30574

/exit or /quit to exit
/settings to change port, emulator serviceurl, bot endpoint, appId and appSecret settings
/dump [#] to show contents of last # activitys (default: 1)
/attachment [path] <- to add a file to your activity

Current settings:
Port:                9000
Emulator ServiceUrl: http://localhost:9000/
Bot Endpoint:        http://localhost:3978/api/messages
BotId:               Bot1
AppId:               disabled
AppPassword:         disabled

Send message to bot:
hi
User1 said:
 hi
/home/admin/Documents/botjs/BotFrameworkEmulator-Console/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.Core.dll Error : 0 : System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.ChannelEmulator+<VerifyAuthentication>d__63' from assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.ChannelEmulator+<<StartServer>b__61_0>d.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
/home/admin/Documents/botjs/BotFrameworkEmulator-Console/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.Core.dll Error : 0 : System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Emulator.ChannelEmulator+<<StartServer>b__61_0>d.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How can I resolve this issue in ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a known issue that the bot builder team is already tracking. Check the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/984).